# what is difference between photoshop text and android textview?

Tags: android, textview, photoshop

I'm developing an android app that allows templates to edit. we are making templates in photoshop. our problem is we make text in photoshop with fix width, height, font and font size. but while we use same dimensions with android textview it gives totally different view.

Is there any way to draw same text in android studio like photoshop?

Android TextView
[image]

PhotoShop TextView
[image]

Answer (score 0):

Your TextView is too small for the text to fit. Why don't you set the width and the height as a wrap content? That way the whole text will be displayed and not only part of it.

Comment: No, I have to use same dimensions like Photoshop and both must be look exactly same.

Comment: Photoshop pixels are different from Android pixels... Try using wrap content as I said it will look exactly the same